# Can I use spring boot datasource to get connection object so as to use it with conn.executeQuery() manually?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I am working on spring boot application with Mysql backend and trying to use springboots datasource Bean to get connection object so as to use it with the following stmts:

```
stmt =conn.createStatement() 
stmt.executeQuery("show tables");
```

which is expected to return the table list. Below is the code of connection class:

```
public class Test {

@Autowired
DataSource datasource;

public void test1(){
      System.out.println("Inside Test Method");
    try {
         Connection conn = datasource.getConnection();
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("show tables");
         while (rs.next()) {
             System.out.println(rs.getString("TableNames"));
         }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println("Null Pointer exception");
    }

  }
```

}

But the datasource object is throwing null value and hence it doesnt return any connection object.

Following is the application.yml

```
spring:
 datasource:
 url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
 driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 username: ****
 password: ****
 initial-size: 1
 max-idle: 2
 max-active: 3
```

Ideally the datasource object should read these properties and be able to return connection object. Not sure if my understanding is correct.

Can anyone help me out in figuring the issue pls ?

Comment: How is that `Test` class constructed? If you are doing a `new Test()` somewhere tha tisn't spring managed and will get nothing injected. But why do you want to work with a plain `DataSource` at least use a `JdbcTemplate`. Your code is also flawed and when executed multple times lead to datasource starvation (as you aren't handling connection closing properly).

Comment: +1 as I couldnt vote, Thanks Deinum, Adding @Autowired while calling the Test class solved the issue. Also regarding usage of plain DataSource, isnt it a good practice to use DataSource rather then a  JdbcTemplate ?

Comment: No it's not. If you have the choice, use `JdbcTemplate` or any other mechanism where you avoid closing resources yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think spring boot automated this process completely. One doesn't have to inject the data source manually & connection pool mechanism is also automated. Just adding the connection properties and pool properties in yaml file or properties file under src/main/resources. It will inject the data source for you.